# Participant recruitment agencies - recommendations

Tags: research, career-development, jobs, hiring

Can anyone recommend a good recruitment agency for sourcing participants for UT?

I've used Saros, Criteria and Qualtel recently (London / South East England), they've all been OK, but I thought it'd be useful to collate a list here.

Answer (score 4):

I've used Criteria & Saros and also recently used Schlesinger Associates.
I've found them all much of a muchness re: price/quality/service etc.

Comment: Qualtel seems to be substantially cheaper than criteria, but I'll get back to you when I know what the quality of the recruitment is like (they are currently doing a job for me).

Answer (score 3):

We use Criteria for all our UT but would be interested to see what other companies get recommended. Just asked a friend and they just suggested taking a look at the [AQR directory](http://www.aqr.org.uk/dir/directory.shtml) (Association for Qualitative Research). Hopefully that'll be of some help.

Comment: The 'recruitment supplier section on AQR looks very useful, thanks for the link! However, there seems to be a fair number of false positives in there, i.e. research companies who do their own internal recruitment. Not sure if they'd offer competitive deals for pure recruitment outsourcing...

Answer (score 3):

I have used Criteria for over 30 user research projects. They are very professional, methodical and thorough. Some of my projects were in financial services and required the recruitment of specialists within particular financial instruments that are known to be difficult to recruit. Time after time Criteria did a superb job, found the right participants and managed the logistics extremely well.

Answer (score 3):

I've only used Saros. Quite happy with them.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Criteria for a number of years. Their service is reliable and flexible. Completely recommend them for finding a broad range of people for user research.

Comment: Ofer, Matt, - I agree Criteria are good, but they are also among the most expensive I've used.

Answer (score 2):

I just did this & seemed to help if you try searching for "market research recruiting"
In doing so, I found this big list:

http://www.greenbook.org/market-research-firms.cfm/focus-group-recruiting

-Rachel

Comment: Qualitative market research recruiters should be fine - at the end of the day User Testing is just a kind of 'Depth Interview (Market Research Terminology)' - but in front of a screen.

Answer (score 1):

I can highly reccomend Magnetic Field;

http://www.magnetic-field.co.uk/services/

They have never let me down and I have been using them for over 3 years now

:)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend Focus4People (http://www.focus4people.com/) - they're small, competitively priced, and were recommended to me by Jeff van Campen, who got them from Alison Austen.